# error in count_combinations in statar

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to test out the count_combinations function in the statar package, and I'm encountering the following problem:

Here's the code:

```
id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2) 
name <- c("coca cola company", "coca cola incorporated",
          "apple incorporated", "apple corp") 
count_combinations(name, id = id)
```

And here's the error:

```
Error in setorderv(x, cols, order, na.last) : 
  some columns are not in the data.table: c,c,1,1,-1
```

What's the reason for getting this error?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such function in the `statar` package.

Comment: https://github.com/matthieugomez/statar/blob/master/R/count_combinations.R

Comment: OK, so not in the stable cran version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next time, when asking a question regarding an unstable version on GitHub, please mention that

So the problem comes [from the following line](https://github.com/matthieugomez/statar/blob/master/R/count_combinations.R#L34)

```
setorder(dt, c("id", "count_across", "count_within"), order = c(1,1,-1))
```

The problem with this line is that quoted names were parsed to the `setorder` function, while the documentation clearly says

> Do not quote column names

So you have two choices here (you will have to copy/modify the function manually in order to do that using the [link provided by @Khashaa](https://github.com/matthieugomez/statar/blob/master/R/count_combinations.R))

Either use `setorderv` instead which has the `col` parameter that can accept quoted column names

```
setorderv(dt, c("id", "count_across", "count_within"), order = c(1,1,-1))
```

Or, do not quote the column names and put `-` in the correct place

```
setorder(dt, id, count_across, -count_within)
```

I went ahead and [filled a FR for you](https://github.com/matthieugomez/statar/issues/2)

---

**Edit**

Te source code on GitHub [has been fixed](https://github.com/matthieugomez/statar/issues/2) and you can re-download from GitHub and and it will work now.